# What is the corresponding code for finding the state of a qubit on the Bloch sphere?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, programming, q#, bloch-sphere

To find the state of a qubit on the *Bloch sphere* we use the following formula:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle=\mathrm{cos}\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle+\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}\mathrm{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle
\end{equation}
Is there any built-in function/operation for that in Q#? If not, how to implement this formula in the Q# code? I'm interested in both preparing a qubit in this state given the two angles, and finding the angles given a qubit in some unknown state.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? Do you want to prepare a qubit in this state given the two angular parameters, or do you want to find the angles given a qubit in some unknown state?

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova Both cases are intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prepare a qubit in state $|\psi\rangle=\mathrm{cos}\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle+\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}\mathrm{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle$, given the angles $\psi$ and $\theta$.**

Let's start with a qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state, as is customary for Q#.

- You can use one of the general library operations to prepare the state, such as [PrepareArbitraryState](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystate).
- Or you can easily do it yourself using a sequence two gates:

  - [Ry($\theta$)](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.ry) will transform the qubit from the $|0\rangle$ state to $|\psi\rangle=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle+\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle$,
  - [R1($\phi$)](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1) will further transform that state into the state you need.

---

**Figure out the angles $\psi$ and $\theta$, given a qubit in some unknown state.**

This is not possible to do in Q#, unless you're willing to do some hacks that will not work on a quantum device. Since real quantum systems don't allow you to peek into their state to get their exact coefficients, Q# doesn't allow you to do this on language level either.

However, if you're running a program on a full-state simulator, you can work around this and use [DumpMachine](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpmachine) function to output the qubit state and then analyze it. Here is an example of such output for state $|-i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|0\rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt2}|1\rangle$:

```
# wave function for qubits with ids (least to most significant): 0
∣0❭:     0.707107 +  0.000000 i  ==     ***********          [ 0.500000 ]     --- [  0.00000 rad ]
∣1❭:     0.000000 + -0.707107 i  ==     ***********          [ 0.500000 ]    ↓    [ -1.57080 rad ]
```

Given the complex amplitudes of the state, you can figure out $\psi$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you so much.